# What options are there for tuning Linux file system caching?

Tags: linux, filesystems, cache, ext3, sysctl

What various types of caching are possible in the ext3 file system and how can their values be changed using system calls or other methods? I don't want to use commands or tools.

Comment: In the unix world, commands and tools ARE the world. If you want to know how to do something with system calls the best thing to do is look through the source code for the tools. However, rather than re-implementing those things it is highly recommended that you use the tools so that you don't have to keep up with file system development progress!

Comment: You'll find most of what you want with the `sysctl` command and similar tools, mostly under the fs tree.  Try running the command `sysctl fs`.  Documentation can be found http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/